# Custom IEqualityComparer to get distinct objects from two lists faster than using .Where() + .Any()

Tags: c#, list, object, distinct, iequalitycomparer

so I've got two lists of objects, objects have multiple fields, but I'd like to distinct them basing on only two of them.

To give you the picture, object KeyAndValue consists of fields Key and Tag, so:

```
list1 = { obj1(key=1,tag=A), obj2(key=2,tag=A) }
list2 = { obj3(key=1,tag=A), obj4(key=2,tag=B) }
```

I'm currently using:

```
list1.Where(x => !list2.Any(y => y.key == x.key)).ToList();
```

The correct result is: obj1, obj2 and obj4 as obj3 has the same key and tag as obj1

What I'm trying to accomplish is to speed this process up as with a lot of objects it takes much too long. I found that custom IEqualityComparer could help here, so I've written my own basing on [MS Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx)
It looks like this:

```
class KeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyAndValue>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyAndValue x, KeyAndValue y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.key == y.key && x.tag == y.tag;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(KeyAndValue keyAndValue)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(keyAndValue, null))
            return 0;
        int hashKeyAndValueKey = keyAndValue.key == null ? 0 : keyAndValue.key.GetHashCode();
        int hashKeyAndValueTag = keyAndValue.tag == null ? 0 : keyAndValue.tag.GetHashCode();
        return hashKeyAndValueKey ^ hashKeyAndValueTag;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
list1.Except(list2, new KeyComparer()).ToList();
```

Unfortunately it does only remove duplicates from list2. It seems that it does not even touch list1 and I do not know if it's the fault of my custom comparer, the way I use it or maybe I should use another method. I've been looking through other questions but could not find a working answer (or at least one that I'd actually know how to implement properly).

Comment: Neither of your methods will return `obj4`. Are you seeking for `Union`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan Steinegger (whom I thank grately for the effort and time spent) mentioned in the first comment that neither of my methods return obj4 I found an issue and decided to implement totally different approach. Now my KeyAndValue class has also an int Hash field, when a constructor is called Hash field is filled with `key.GetHashCode() ^ tag.GetHashCode()`. It simplified the comparison as now I'm first combining list1 with list2 and then sending it through: `CombinedList.GroupBy(x => x.Hash).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();` Results seem to be correct :)

Comment: Weird. I still don't understand what you want. Be careful when dealing with hash codes. They do not replace a real comparison. The hash is only a performance improvement to avoid calling an expensive `Equals` when the hash is already different. **Equal hashes however do not mean equal values!** Equal hashes mean that you have to call `Equals`. It looks weird that you group by the hash code. `GroupBy` should also be able to take a comparer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `Except`. You want to have distinct values of both?

```
var distinctValues = list1.Union(list2).Distinct();
```

You need to either implement `GetHashCode`/`Equals` in `KeyAndValue` or use a comparer to compare the objects by key and value.

---

*(Old stuff bellow)*

Not sure whether I understand the question correctly. Could it be that you didn't recognize that Except create a new IEnumerable and ToList a new List?

try:

```
var list1AdditionalItems = list1.Except(list2, new KeyComparer()).ToList();
```

and probably also:

```
var list2AdditionalItems = list2.Except(list1, new KeyComparer()).ToList();
```

---

Another observation. in this code:

```
list1.Where(x => !list2.Any(y => y.key == x.key)).ToList();
```

You only check the key. If you want this behaviour, you should write the comparer accordingly:

```
class KeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyAndValue>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyAndValue x, KeyAndValue y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.key == y.key;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(KeyAndValue keyAndValue)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(keyAndValue, null))
            return 0;
        return keyAndValue.key == null ? 0 : keyAndValue.key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

Last but not least: When you need performance, consider using a dictionary instead.

Comment: 1: yes, I'm saving the result to a list

Comment: 2: your KeyComparer did not return objects with the same keys but different tags

Comment: 3: I'm not sure if dictionary would work here, as I mentioned KeyAndValue object consists of more than two fields, so I could create a dictionary<string, List<KeyAndValue> but would it help? I'll try

Comment: What data type does the key have? I mean `Dictionary<KeyType, KeyAndValue>` to quickly find the objects by key.

Comment: Just to make sure: `KeyAndValue` isn't a `struct`, is it?

Comment: It is a class. As you mentioned in your first comment that neither of my methods return obj4 I found an issue and decided to implement totally different approach. Now my KeyAndValue class has also an int Hash field, when a constructor is called Hash field is filled with key.GetHashCode() ^ tag.GetHashCode(). It simplified the comparison as now I'm first combining list1 with list2 and then sending it through: CombinedList.GroupBy(x => x.Hash).Select(y => y.First()).ToList(); Results seem to be correct :)

Comment: And what data type has the key?

Comment: I just saw that you expect distinct values of both lists. See my updated answer (on top of the answer).

Comment: key is a string field, tag is a field of a Tag (another class) object type with a string field name. Now as I think about it perhaps the previous methods were not working in the first place because I compared tag fields returning Tag class object instead od tag.name.